# Singleton, Method & Variable

Tags: objective-c, singleton

i would like just to get answer to this question, i know it is possible with variables, but with method ?

with a singleton, can i use methods + variables anywhere in my project ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A singleton is nothing but a global instance of a class. Once you get the instance anywhere on your project, you're supposed to do whatever you want with it, as you would with any other class instance. Obviously, **you can access it's public variables and methods**.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you won't have to create an instance to access your singleton method.